# Previous N rows until find value not null

Tags: python, pandas

I m trying to implement a simple function that will allow me to iterate back to find a not null value, and this value will be stored in a new column called prv_djma.

**Data**

```
data = {'id_st': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100], 
    'year':  [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018],
    'djma':  [1000, 2200, 0, 3000, 1000, 0, 2000, 0, 0],
    'taux': [np.nan, 0.9, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 0.7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

[image]

```
df['prv_djma'] = df['djma'].shift()
```

[image]

**What I m looking for**

[image]

The goal is to check N lines back until finding a not null djma then put the value in the current line (column prv_djma).

For example the last line with(index 8) has a djma=0 and the (index 7) also is djma=0 so I want to fill the column prv_djma by the djma (index 6).

**Note**

The problem I have is in index 8. all other lines are correct.

Comment: Did you hit submit before finishing your post, or is this all you got?

Comment: @cs95 I'm trying to rephrase my question to make it clear to everyone. Sorry if it causes problems

Comment: @adilblanco first, please post the data as text ([no images please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)), secondly, the question isnt very clear, can you explain the logic a bit more? Thanks

Comment: @anky_91 I updated my question I hope it's clear now. Thank you

Comment: What would you want to happen if the first three rows had 0 for djma? Should the output be `NaN NaN NaN 0 3000` for the first 5 rows?

Comment: @ALollz Thank you for the answer, My ultimate goal is that when I don't have a djma for a year I can use the one from previous years (the nearest year).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `shift`, ensuring that if there are consecutive 0s we then fill with the previous value:

```
m = df.djma.eq(0)
df['prv_djma'] = df.djma.shift().mask((m == m.shift()) & m).ffill()
```

#### Output:

```
   id_st  year  djma  taux  prev_djma
0    100  2010  1000   NaN        NaN
1    100  2011  2200   0.9     1000.0
2    100  2012     0   1.1     2200.0
3    100  2013  3000   1.2        0.0
4    100  2014  1000   1.3     3000.0
5    100  2015     0   1.4     1000.0
6    100  2016  2000   1.5        0.0
7    100  2017     0   1.6     2000.0
8    100  2018     0   0.7     2000.0
```

---

For groups you need to do this separately so that `.shift` doesn't spill outside of the group.

```
def get_prv(x):
    m = x.eq(0)
    return x.shift().mask((m == m.shift()) & m).ffill()

df['prv_djma'] = df.groupby('id_st')['djma'].apply(get_prv)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, In my case I have many ['id_st'], I tried with groupby `df['prv_djma'] = df.groupby('id_st')['djma'].shift().mask((m == m.shift()) & m).ffill()` but doesn't work any suggestion

Comment: @adilblanco See my update, make it a function, then apply to the groupby.